# No Inhouse option in member center - IOS distribution

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

There's no In-house option while creating distribution profile. Any idea why?

I could create a certificate using In-house and Ad-Hoc options. But not able to create distribution profile for In house distribution

[image]

Comment: You actually finished making the In House certificate right?  And it is not expired?

Comment: No.. its a new account.. Not expired

Comment: Yes.. i have made the in house certificate

Comment: I guess you should send an Email to Apple then.

Comment: Ok.. how do i do that? Bug report?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/contact/